# Codigo en python arroja un error que no logro arreglar

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, revisión-de-código, ciencia-de-datos

Estoy estudiando python y ciencia de datos. Estoy haciendo un Lab para comparar y evaluar los datos de un barrio de Barcelona y luego compararlos contra uno de Toronto.

La cuestión es que he obtenido los datos del barrio de Toronto, su latitud y longitud (es para luego graficarlo en un mapa), y he hecho una iteración para que el programa cuente la cantidad de tiendas por Barrio para luego poder hacer la comparativa con Barcelona, pero al ejecutarlo me da un error.

Este es el Código:

```
for i in np.arange(37,finaldf.shape[0]):

    # We choose to search by category with a 500m radius.
    radius = 500
    LIMIT = 100
    category_id = '4bf58dd8d48988d102951735' #ID for Accessory stores

    latitude = finaldf['Latitude'][i]
    longitude = finaldf['Longitude'][i]

    # Define the corresponding URL
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&categoryId={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, category_id, radius, LIMIT)

    # Send the GET Request
    results = requests.get(url).json()

    # Get relevant part of JSON and transform it into a pandas dataframe
    # assign relevant part of JSON to venues 
    venues = results['response']['venues']

    # tranform venues into a dataframe
    dataframe = json_normalize(venues)
    dataframe.head()

    # keep only columns that include venue name, and anything that is associated with location
    filtered_columns = ['name', 'categories'] + [col for col in dataframe.columns if col.startswith('location.')] + ['id']
    dataframe_filtered = dataframe.loc[:, filtered_columns]

    # function that extracts the category of the venue
    def get_category_type(row):
        try:
            categories_list = row['categories']
        except:
            categories_list = row['venue.categories']

        if len(categories_list) == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return categories_list[0]['name']

    # filter the category for each row
    dataframe_filtered['categories'] = dataframe_filtered.apply(get_category_type, axis=1)

    # clean column names by keeping only last term
    dataframe_filtered.columns = [column.split('.')[-1] for column in dataframe_filtered.columns]

    print(str(i) + ') The number of shops in ' + finaldf['Neighbourhood'][i] + ' is ' + str(dataframe_filtered.shape[0]) + '\n')
    N_shop.append(dataframe_filtered.shape[0])
```

Y este el error que arroja:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         6     category_id = '4bf58dd8d48988d102951735' #ID for Accessory stores
>         7 
>   ----> 8     latitude = finaldf['Latitude'][i]
>         9     longitude = finaldf['Longitude'][i]
>        10
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py
>   in **getitem**(self, key)
>       866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
>       867         try:
>   --> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>       869 
>       870             if not is_scalar(result):
>
> /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py
>   in get_value(self, series, key)    4372         try:    4373
>   return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
>   -> 4374                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))    4375         except KeyError
>   as e1:    4376             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer()
>   or self.is_boolean()):
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 38

No logro comprender el porque. Si alguien puede iluminarme con sus conocimientos lo agradecería, sí hace falta más información con gusto se las daré.

Gracias!!

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo del JSON que obtienes?

Comment: Creo que el error que te esta dando es probablemente por que tu dataframe `finaldf` no contiene ninguna fila con el indice 38. Cuando el buble for pasa al valor 38 no lo encuentra cuando asignas `latitude = finaldf['Latitude'][i]` que no encuentra el valor correspondiente.

Comment: Graicas por la respuesta. He revisado el df y había un error al obtener los datos. He pedido solucionarlo. Disculpa que no haya contestado antes pero estaba de viaje y no pude mirarlo hasta que volví